# Эмуляция нажатия клавиш

Tags: jquery

Доброго времени суток! Как эмулировать нажатие клавиши?

Comment: Событие то программно можно вызвать, а вот действия всё равно не будет.

Answer (score 2):

Эмулировать нажатие клавиши (как и любое другое событие) можно функцией `trigger`. [Документация](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

Comment: я пытаюсь сделать кнопки для управления флеш игрой на сайте - как сделать, чтобы игра получила фокус и сработало нажатие клавиши?

Comment: Тогда читайте про [ExternalInterface][2] в ActionScript. [Вот здесь][1] есть пример его использования.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639609/javascript-jquery-flash-as3-interaction
  [2]: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

Comment: а если игра не моя? других вариантов нет?

Comment: Насколько мне известно, нет. А зачем вам управлять чужой Flash-игрой из JavaScript? Пишите бота? Для этого можно использовать и другие технологии.

Comment: сайт будет отображаться на сенсорном интерфейсе - физических кнопок не будет

Comment: Тогда декомпилировать игру и собрать заново, вставив ExternalInterface. Такой подход наверняка нарушает какой-нибудь закон или лицензионное соглашение, но это единственный способ решения этой задачи, который приходит мне в голову.